# How to search for classes annotated with a given annotation in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, ejb

I have a project where many classes have one and the same simple name, but are decorated with different annotations.

For example:

```
package com.example.base;

@Default
public class ClassName { }
```

and

```
package com.example.country;

@SomeCountrySpecific
public class ClassName extends com.example.base.ClassName { }
```

There are many classes like these within the project and all are EJB injected within other classes' constructors/setters.

In IntelliJ, when I want to navigate to some class, I can type only the class name and the IDE finds all the classes and gives back a list of options. You can imagine that this lists often consists of more than 15-20 different classes and navigating and finding the desired one is difficult.

However, I would like to open a class, which has a name equal to `ClassName` **and** is annotated with some annotation (like `@SomeCountrySpecific`).

Is this possible in IntelliJ?

Please note that renaming the sub-classes is not an option.

Comment: For stuff like this, I usually use "Find in path" and then use both the search field and file field to narrow it to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well...I am open to any solutions on this - both customizing the build-in feature or installing a plug-in. It's just tedious to traverse over a list of same class names. That's why I'd like to apply an annotation filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very elegant or all that convenient, but this might get you what you're looking for (?).  You can use the file mask and "Text to find" to search for annotations in files named by some pattern.

[image]

Comment: Nice! It's far better than what I have now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try Edit-Find-Search Structurally.

Comment: Thanks, that's an option, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use navigation by class name (Ctrl+N) to open the file where the annotation is defined and then run "Find Usages" (Alt+F7) on its name.

Using this approach you will have autocompletion for annotation names which can be much longer that `@SomeCountrySpecific`